# How to check alphabet sorting with cypress

Tags: sorting, testing, automated-tests, cypress, alphabetical-sort

I have a 2 variables and want to checking alphabetically sort for its.

This is my code

```
cy.get('.list-item').eq(1)
  .find('.activity-name span')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => {
    const first = text;
    cy.get('.activity').click();
    cy.get('.list-item').eq(1)
    .find('.activity-name span')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(text => {
        const second = text;
        // Here I want to check if the result of first element  is equal second-variable
     });
});
```

Pls help me. How can I do it with cypress

Comment: I am a bit confused here. You said you want to check alphabetical sorting but in your code you want to compare the value of two variables. You can simply use javascript if else to compare the values.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, I couldn't have a hardcoded list here, so I used the above (from @Hung Tran) to have a more generic solution:

```js
cy.get('.list-item')
    .then(items => {
      const unsortedItems = items.map((index, html) => Cypress.$(html).text()).get();
      const sortedItems = unsortedItems.slice().sort();
      expect(unsortedItems, 'Items are sorted').to.deep.equal(sortedItems);
    });
```

It works well on Cypress 5.3.0

Answer (score 4):

Given the list below

```html
      <ul>
        <li class="list-item">Alaska</li>
        <li class="list-item">Colorado</li>
        <li class="list-item">Delaware</li>
      </ul>
```

Here is how to check if it's sorted

```js
  it('should be sorted', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('.list-item')
      .then($items => {
        return $items.map((index, html) => Cypress.$(html).text()).get()
      })
      .should('deep.eq', ['Alaska', 'Colorado', 'Delaware'])
  })
```

Comment: Can be further simplified to `cy.get('.list-item').invoke('text').should('eq', ['Alaska', 'Colorado', 'Delaware'].join(''));`

Comment: I had the same thought. The downside of this idea is when it fails, the error message is not helpful. The best approach is to define a custom command, textArrays, which does the logic of then block.

Comment: Also you could use some Chai plugin like chai-sorted. You can extend Cypress with chai plugins.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but it's not  working, when I use like this.then(text => {
        const second = text;
       .should('deep.eq', [second, first])
     });

Comment: @NarinePoghosyan it's a specific example because I don't know exactly what your code looks like. You should modify it based on your own need.

Comment: I have a table, And when clicking in row-title that rows result is sorting. I already take a results after and before clicking on sort button. Its my first and second variables. Now I want to check if that sorting button working right.

Comment: @HungTran One question, what does  `_,` means inside the `$items.map((_, html) =>.......`

Comment: @soccerway it's actually the index because it's unused so I named it as _ . Just a practice from Python.

Comment: Good to know that !